# TypeError: object.function is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I have 2 files QueryExecution.js and app.js; from app.js am calling a function query_result which is in QueryExecution.js. But when I made the call in app.js am getting object.function is not a function.

Kindly apologize for any stupid mistakes :( Thanks in advance for your time and help

I tried to print the object(realtime_chart_new) that I created to call the function. the object is printing the entire function content.

## QueryExecution.js

```
function query_result(connection,sql) {
    .......query statements and processing content .....
        return CountOrders, TotalAmt;
}
module.exports = query_result;
```

## app.js

````
var connection = {
    .....connection statements .....
};

var realtime_chart_new = require('./QueryExecution.js');
var SalesCountOrders, SalesTotalAmt = realtime_chart_new.query_result(connection,sql);```



#Below is the error statements:

var SalesCountOrders, SalesTotalAmt = realtime_chart_new.query_result(connection,sql);
TypeError: realtime_chart_new.query_result is not a function
````

Comment: Does `realtime_chart_new` contain `query_result`, or is it printing the entire function directly? Also, what is exported from the file 'QueryExecution.js' ?

Comment: ``realtime_chart_new`` directly prints the entire code that I wrote inside ``query_result``

Comment: That would *probably* mean `realtime_chart_new` is default export and you would need to call it directly like `realtime_chart_new()`

Comment: That's great !!!! it worked !!! But I didn't understand how it worked with just object name and without function name. Pls, post this as the answer. I'll mark it as accepted. Thank you so much :)

Comment: To add answer, edit your question to reflect the way you've exported in your `QueryExecution.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have overridden module exports with query_result, so now `require('./QueryExecution.js')` returns a function.

This will give you expected result:

```
module.exports.query_result = query_result;
```

OR

```
module.exports = {
    query_result: query_result
};
```